# Asking about FOSS Project Merging method, here or in SO?

Tags: discussion

First, a bit of background:

I am planning to "takeover" the maintaining of several inter-related FOSS project. Because the projects are very strongly intertwined, I am going to merge the repositories into one. At the same time, I will migrate the project(s) from SVN (at SourceForge) to Mercurial (at BitBucket).

I need to discuss the method, the 'how' to do the merging, in a way that the current maintainer can still finish his backlog while gradually handing over the project to me. And at the same time, I can start development branches on feature improvements and/or intricate/complex bugfixes.

I already thought of several possible migration methods, with each option's pros & cons. But I think I need input from fellow programmers, just in case I overlooked some drawbacks/benefits. Better to design the 'flow' right in the beginning rather than doing an overhaul later.

Now, this kind of question, would it be more suitable for Programmers SE or for StackOverflow?

Comment: related: [Where does my git question go?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6311/where-does-my-git-question-go)

Comment: @gnat Thanks! The answer there is really complete and helpful!